# mapstruct How to convert a list of object to list of interface?

Tags: java, list, mapstruct

I have below interface and classes

```
public interface Fruit { ... }

public class AppleDto implements Fruit {...}

public class AppleEntity { ... }
```

I have created a mapper, which converts `List` of `AppleEntity` to `List` of `AppleDto` but I need return type to be `List` of `Fruit`.

```
@Mapper
public interface FruitsMapper {
    FruitsMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(FruitsMapper.class);

    @IterableMapping(elementTargetType = AppleDto.class)
    List<Fruit> entityToFruits(List<AppleEntity> entity);
}
```

It's not allowing me to convert to list of interface and giving an error. Is there a proper way to achieve what I need?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a single mapping method between `AppleEntity` and `Fruit` and define the result type via `@BeanMapping#resultType`

In your case it will look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface FruitsMapper {
    FruitsMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(FruitsMapper.class);

    @BeanMapping(resultType = AppleDto.class)
    Fruit map(AppleEntity entity);

    List<Fruit> entityToFruits(List<AppleEntity> entity);
}
```

Using `@IterableMapping#elementTargetType` is not what you are expecting. It is just a selection criteria when there are multiple mapping methods possible. From it's javadoc:

```
Specifies the type of the element to be used in the result of the mapping method in case multiple mapping
methods qualify.
```